# Passing model id through rails route in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, simple-form

I'm calling a custom action with simple_form. I'm having trouble passing the `:id` parameter to the action.

**routes**

```
post '/posts/:id/admin_vote' => 'posts#admin_vote', as: 'admin_vote'
```

**form**

```
<%= simple_form_for :post, url: admin_vote_path(:post_id), :html => {:class => 'form-inline admin-vote-form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :vote, 1..20 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Vote', :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
<% end %>
```

**partial render**

```
<%= render 'layouts/admin_vote', :locals => { :post => post, :post_id => post.id } %>
```

For some reason the action receives `params[:id] = 'post_id'` instead of the actual id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me your form should be

```
<%= simple_form_for post, url: admin_vote_path, :html => {:class => 'form-inline admin-vote-form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :vote, 1..20 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Vote', :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
<% end %>
```

you should build form based on variable `post`

Comment: I thought to do this initially, but it crashes my app. I get a strange  `[Bug]Segmentation Fault` error that has nothing to do with the form.

Comment: You're correct. I had to add `:partial => ...` to the render as well to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're providing `:post_id` symbol to the `admin_vote_path`, so it uses that. Change it to:

```
admin_vote_path(params[:post_id])
```

or a different parameter depending on the context of your form.

Comment: This doesn't work because the form is on an index page that doesn't have a post_id paramater